# Probability of getting (6,5) on consecutive throws before getting a (6,6) on consecutive throws of a die.

Tags: probability, dice

Suppose we throw a die until we get either (6,5) or (6,6) on consecutive throws. What is the probability that we'll get to (6,5) before (6,6) ?

Comment: Obviously:  $50\%$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously:  $50\%$.  Nothing matters until you get a $6$.  Then it is equally likely your next roll is a $5$ or a $6$.

Comment: Thanks! I was also thinking same but not sure. Btw how will the answer change if we change (6,5)&&(6,6) to say (6,5) and (3,4)?

Comment: Yep.  But if you want to blow your mind, look up Penney's paradox or Penney's game:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penney%27s_game

Comment: @PrabhatSharma There is no conflict between the options $(6,5)$ and $(3,4)$ so they're equally likely to happen too. Again $\frac12$.